# Server errors in Google appscript while using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, server-error

I am using firebase library for appscript [Firebase for appscript](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)

It was working successfully in the web app which I deployed using appscript itself for last two months. Suddenly since last few days, it is not working and showing this error
[image: Error]

There were no logical errors in code, as I saw it happening myself while debugging recently. For example these two lines I ran separately. It gave error first, then worked after few minutes later.

```
var firebaseUrl = "https://[myfirebaseurl]/";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, '[secret]');
```

I tried other authenticating measures like auth, but that too behaved similarly. Moreover while it was showing server error inside v8 runtime environment, I tried accessing database using a different python script and it worked smoothly. What could be the problem?

Comment: Also, setting read and write null in rules of firebase doesn't help.

Comment: Server errors rarely have a user diagnosable problem. The only thing you can do is copy everything to  a new instances:-new sheets, new webapp, new publish, new project. Restart from scratch.

Comment: @TheMaster I tried, but same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

### If the error occurs only sporadically you can catch it with a `try...catch` statement

Sample:

```js
function getData(){
  var firebaseUrl = "https://[myfirebaseurl]/";
  try {
    var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, '[secret]');
  }
  catch (err) {
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    getData();
  }
}
```

Comment: [20-09-12 18:23:30:610 IST] Error: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
    at FirebaseApp_._sendAllRequests(Code:659:11)
    at FirebaseApp_._buildAllRequests(Code:520:16)
    at baseClass_.getData(Code:224:28)                                                           [I logged the error]

Comment: If the error keeps persisting either double-check if the firebase URL and  your credentials are still valid. Also: did you bind your script to a standard GCP recently? If you did not change anything and the error persists -consider filing a bug report on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your "oauthScopes" in Manifest file (appscript.json) with 3 URLs.

```
 "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
```

As per suggested : [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-via-oauth-2-access-token)